# Can you refer to a two-worded phrase as a "word"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

For example, could I say, "My favorite word these days is 'suburban wasteland'"?

Anything else seems awkward:

- My favorite phrase
- My favorite expression
- My favorite term

Comment: You can say it...but need to be prepared for getting "That's two words!" as a response. Why do you find the other possibilities awkward?

Comment: 'Expression' covers single orthographic words and some longer strings (collocations (weak ... strong), open compounds). But free combinations (eg _distant forest_) are probably better not regarded as such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not consider "suburban wasteland" a word. The reasons are as follows.

Some words are identified as a compound word, e.g. real estate, ice cream and high school, which consists of two words. The combinations are commonly used with a fixed meaning. For example, ice cream always means a cold sweet dessert but not a lotion or a yellowish liquid with ice.

According to Cambridge Dictionary, a compound is "a word that combines two or more different words. Often, the meaning of the compound cannot be discovered by knowing the meaning of the different words that form it. Compounds may be written either as one word or as separate words."

I reckon that the two words together "suburban wasteland" are not a compound or a single word while the meaning of the combination is explicit and they are just two words, i.e. an adjective and a noun, meaning wasteland in a suburb. For instance, there is no definition of the combination in Cambridge Dictionary.

I prefer "term" or I would say, "my favourite topic these days is suburban wasteland". Disclaimer: I am bad at English.

Comment: Welcome to the site. The answer is helpful, humble, lovely.

Comment: Yes. [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Suburban%20Wasteland) is probably granting the expression too much recognition too quickly.